# How does the parameter weights work in scipy.spatial.distance.cosine?

Tags: python, scipy, cosine-similarity, weighted

Scipy has added a new optional parameter weights to `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` function. How does the weighting work?

Is it like both vectors are multiplied by weights and then normal cosine similarity is taken?
Or is it like cosine similarity, but each term in the numerator is multiplied by its corresponding weight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [my answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/448904/216706), scipy multiplies square root of the weights to both the vectors and then computes cosine similarity between the vectors.